# Dependency injection in (Python) Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dependency-injection

I want to achieve maximum testability in my [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) app which I'm writing in Python.

Basically what I'm doing is creating an all-purpose base handler which inherits the `google.appengine.ext.webapp.RequestHandler`. My base handler will expose common functionality in my app such as repository functions, a session object and the like.

When the `WSGIApplication` receives a request it will find the handler class that has been registered for the requested URL, and call its constructor and after that it will call a method called `initialize` passing in the `request` and `response` objects.

Now, for the sake of testability I want to be able to "*mock*" these objects (along with my own objects). So my question is how do I go about injecting these mocks? I can override the `initialize` method in my base handler and check for some global "test flag" and initialize some dummy `request` and `response` objects. But it seems wrong (in *my* mind at least). And how do I go about initializing my other objects (which may depend on the `request` and `response` objects)?

As you can probably tell I'm a little new to Python so any recommendations would be most welcome.

**EDIT:**

It has been pointed out to me that this question was a little hard to answer without some code, so here goes:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from ..utils import gmemsess
from .. import errors
_user_id_name = 'userid'

class Handler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    '''
    classdocs
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.charset = 'utf8'
        self._session = None

    def _getsession(self):
        if not self._session:
            self._session = gmemsess.Session(self)
        return self._session

    def _get_is_logged_in(self):
        return self.session.has_key(_user_id_name)

    def _get_user_id(self):
        if not self.is_logged_in:
            raise errors.UserNotLoggedInError()
        return self.session[_user_id_name]

    session = property(_getsession)
    is_logged_in = property(_get_is_logged_in)
    user_id = property(_get_user_id)
```

As you can see, no dependency injection is going on here at all. The session object is created by calling `gmemsess.Session(self)`. The `Session` class expects a class which has a `request` object on it (it uses this to read a cookie value). In this case, `self` does have such a property since it inherits from `webapp.RequestHandler`. It also only has the object on it because after calling (the empty) constructor, `WSGIApplication` calls a method called `initialize` which sets this object (and the response object). The initialize method is declared on the base class (`webapp.RequestHandler`).
It looks like this:

```
def initialize(self, request, response):
    """Initializes this request handler with the given Request and 
     Response."""
    self.request = request
    self.response = response
```

When a request is made, the `WSGIApplication` class does the following:

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """Called by WSGI when a request comes in."""
    request = self.REQUEST_CLASS(environ)
    response = self.RESPONSE_CLASS()
    WSGIApplication.active_instance = self
    handler = None
    groups = ()
    for regexp, handler_class in self._url_mapping:
        match = regexp.match(request.path)
        if match:
            handler = handler_class()
            handler.initialize(request, response)
            groups = match.groups()
            break

    self.current_request_args = groups
    if handler:
        try:
            method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD']
            if method == 'GET':
                handler.get(*groups)
            elif method == 'POST':
                handler.post(*groups)
            '''SNIP'''
```

The lines of interest are those that say:

```
     handler = handler_class()
     handler.initialize(request, response)
```

As you can see, it calls the empty constructor on my handler class. And this is a problem for me, because what I think I would like to do is to inject, at runtime, the type of my session object, such that my class would look like this instead (fragment showed):

```
    def __init__(self, session_type):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        self.charset = 'utf8'
        self._session = None
        self._session_type = session_type

    def _getsession(self):
        if not self._session:
            self._session = self._session_type(self)
        return self._session
```

However I can't get my head around how I would achieve this, since the `WSGIApplication` only calls the empty constructor. I guess I could register the `session_type` in some global variable, but that does not really follow the philosophy of dependency injection (as I understand it), but as stated I'm new to Python, so maybe I'm just thinking about it the wrong way. In any event I would rather pass in a session object instead of it's type, but this looks kind of impossible here.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some code demonstrating the steps you've outlined here?  It would help us provide concrete answers.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder, I have elaborated some more on my question.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder it just dawned on me, while thinking of your response to my earlier question, that python will probably not prevent me from overriding/inheriting from the `WSGIApplication` which is the main entry point for all requests. So I should probably just do that, and inject all my dependencies there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to create a module-level variable containing the class of the session to create:

```
# myhandler.py
session_class = gmemsess.Session

class Handler(webapp.Request
    def _getsession(self):
        if not self._session:
            self._session = session_class(self)
        return self._session
```

then, wherever it is that you decide between testing and running:

```
import myhandler

if testing:
    myhandler.session_class = MyTestingSession
```

This leaves your handler class nearly untouched, leaves the WSGIApplication completely untouched, and gives you the flexibility to do your testing as you want.

Comment: Ok, but then how do you suggest I "mock" the request and response objects? Something along the lines `if testing: myhandler_instance.request = TestRequest()` ?

Comment: request and response are passed into initialize, which you can override.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just test your handlers in isolation? That is, create your mock Request and Response objects, instantiate the handler you want to test, and call handler.initialize(request, response) with your mocks. There's no need for dependency injection here.